# window 10 internet breakdown 'bug'

Tags: internet, windows-networking

After the updation of my window 10.the window is having wifi break down or you can say internet break down.To use internet i have to reconnect the wifi after turning it off.Where as on same time internet is working on my Mobile and macbook.

Comment: Update the BIOS, Chipset if a laptop, LAN and Wi-Fi drivers and Power Manager driver.  Do all these, restart and test.

Comment: add to question: OS tag and what version / build # windows `winver` and `ver`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you may have updated to the Windows 10 1903 edition, which can break down internet connectivity. [This](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-regain-internet-access-after-installing-update-windows-10) might help you get back online.

Comment: That particular issue has already been fixed through an update

Comment: Also the bug did not occur on all computers (none of my own or any client). And also V1909 (current) is fine